# Issue setting up & injecting chrome extension content scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension for a site: poe.trade, but cannot get the extension to inject into that url, or, any url.

I've tried multiple variations of matches for poe.trade in my content_scripts, and now trying to just get it to inject into google.

My current content_scripts looks like this:

```
    {
      "matches": ["https://specificURL/*","https://*/*","http://*/*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "css": ["static/css/main.css"],
      "js": ["static/js/main.js"]
    }
  ],
```

and here's the full project: https://github.com/TeddyAmkie/poe-banlist

The only changes made are in the webpack to remove the hashed filename and the manifest.json.

I'm expecting to see my boilerplate app.js somewhere on the page for now, currently I can't see it at all on the page.

Comment: The posted fragment is correct so it's not the problem. The problem is somewhere inside your project and someone will have to debug it for you. This is not how SO works. Start by verifying the content script is actually added https://puu.sh/EwgSh/221293a54e.png, then proceed with debugging your code. Also it may be helpful to inspect a [demo extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) to quickly learn the basic things about extension architecture.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the response. This was the kind of information I was looking for, just needed a sanity check